# undefined reference to `libusb_xxx'

Tags: c, linux, cmake, libusb

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and CLion to run this in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>

static void print_devs(libusb_device **devs)
{
    libusb_device *dev;
    int i = 0;

    while ((dev = devs[i++]) != NULL) {
        struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
        int r = libusb_get_device_descriptor(dev, &desc);
        if (r < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to get device descriptor");
            return;
        }

        printf("%04x:%04x (bus %d, device %d)\n",
               desc.idVendor, desc.idProduct,
               libusb_get_bus_number(dev), libusb_get_device_address(dev));
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("hello");
    libusb_device **devs;
    int r;
    ssize_t cnt;

    r = libusb_init(NULL);
    if (r < 0)
        return r;

    cnt = libusb_get_device_list(NULL, &devs);
    if (cnt < 0)
        return (int) cnt;

    print_devs(devs);
    libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1);

    libusb_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

It's a `test.c` for `libusb`. However, with `libus-dev` and `libusb-1.0.0-dev` both downloaded, I kept got this error:

```
====================[ Build | usbTool | Debug-System ]==========================
/snap/clion/219/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/wonster/CLionProjects/usb-tool/cmake-build-debug-system --target usbTool -- -j 6
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/usbTool.dir/test.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable usbTool
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/usbTool.dir/test.c.o: in function `print_devs':
/home/wonster/CLionProjects/usb-tool/test.c:12: undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_descriptor'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/wonster/CLionProjects/usb-tool/test.c:20: undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_address'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/wonster/CLionProjects/usb-tool/test.c:20: undefined reference to `libusb_get_bus_number'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/usbTool.dir/test.c.o: in function `main':
/home/wonster/CLionProjects/usb-tool/test.c:31: undefined reference to `libusb_init'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/wonster/CLionProjects/usb-tool/test.c:35: undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_list'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/wonster/CLionProjects/usb-tool/test.c:40: undefined reference to `libusb_free_device_list'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/wonster/CLionProjects/usb-tool/test.c:42: undefined reference to `libusb_exit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/usbTool.dir/build.make:97: usbTool] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/usbTool.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:90: CMakeFiles/usbTool.dir/rule] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:124: usbTool] Error 2
```

I just don't know the reason and how to solve this. I've followed a lot of blogs on Internet but not helpful.

I'm guessing whether there's any wrong with the CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(usbTool C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
#声明头文件路径
#set(INC_DIR /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libusb/1.0.26/include/libusb-1.0)//绝对路径
set(INC_DIR ./include)
#声明链接库路径
#set(LINK_DIR /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libusb/1.0.26/lib)//绝对路径
set(LINK_DIR ./lib)

#引入头文件
include_directories(${INC_DIR})

#引入库文件
link_directories(${LINK_DIR})


add_executable(usbTool test.c)

#引入第三方库
target_link_libraries(usbTool libusb-1.0.a)
```

And this is the project content:

[image]

Any help is remarkable! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you download `libusb-1.0.a` from? Are you sure it's a static library linked for Ubuntu or, at least, Linux? Is the error any different if you don't link it at all, e.g. by commenting out the `target_link_libraries` line altogether?

Comment: I downloaded `libusb-1.0.a` by using `sudo apt install libusb-1.0.a-dev`

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't have the `1.0.a` version, only `1.0-0`. You shouldn't need `include` and `lib` directories then at all, `apt` should put all necessary headers and libraries in proper default places. Also, it's better to link by calling the library's name (`usb-1.0`) instead of full file name (`libusb-1.0.a`)

Comment: Does CMake really hide the actual commands that are called to compile and link?! I never understood, _why_ one would like to have it like this, as it seriously interferes debugging of build problems. You might want to look for options to make them visible, and to [edit] your question to add them.